# Aggregating census tracts and reducing Coefficients of Variation?

Tags: merge, statistics, census

I am working on a project that maps out poverty rates (ACS data) by census tract. Many of the tracts have CV's that are just too high for our study and I am hoping for find a sound methodology in merging neighborhood tracts in hopes of lowering the CV's. At first, I arbitrarily chose which tracts to merge (neighboring tracts that also had high CV's) but I am wondering now if there is a more appropriate method for this. I know how to merge- I am wondering about how to choose which to merge.

Comment: I feel like I should know this, but what is the CV?

Comment: I suppose it is **C**oefficient of **V**ariation.

Comment: Yes. The coefficient of variation. Our group follows a standard of not reporting figures with a CV higher than 30